# How to get Instagram profile?

Tags: instagram-graph-api

How to get user information about himself (real name and avatar) using *Instagram Graph API* or *Instagram Basic Display API*?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started

```
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/me/accounts?access_token={access-token}"
```